# How do I determine if a PayPal account is verified using the new .NET REST Libraries

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

So I installed PayPal.net SDK 1.7.0 in Visual Studio 2010 using the Nuget package. With all my readings this is the 'latest and greatest' and promises to be the most forward compatible library there is from PayPal.

I am having no problem testing the *Payout* functionality, works nicely.

However, before I do a Payout, I would like to determine if the PayPal user is Verified (address, or bank account), before allowing the Payout. The only documentation I can find that describes what I need here is only available in a soon-to-be-deprecated library called 'Adaptive Accounts'.

https://github.com/paypal/adaptiveaccounts-sdk-dotnet

You go right to the GitHub link, and it even recommends NOT to use it. So, how exactly do I achieve this functionality of pre-verification before issuing a Payout?

> This Classic SDK is not actively supported and will be deprecated in
>   the future. For full support on new integrations, please use the
>   PayPal .NET SDK

So do I use it or is this functionality supported in the new libraries I have installed, but just can`t find documentation on?

Comment: can you contact the IT or Technical support department of `PayPal` perhaps their is a `Security Vulnerability` with the existing SDK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our REST API library doesn't have any support for AdaptiveAccounts as of this moment.

If you would like to use Adaptive Accounts API, you will need to use Classic API integration. The specific API you should be using is called `GetVerifiedStatus` API.

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-accounts/GetVerifiedStatus_API_Operation/

If you are looking for a SDK for it, here is the newest SDK available for AdaptiveAccounts: https://www.nuget.org/packages/PayPalAdaptiveAccountsSDK/

This will not be depreciated, at least not anytime soon until REST API supported AdaptiveAccounts API.

Comment: Ok thanks. I see the nuget link has no mention of deprecation. It's the GitHub copy of it that I found first on a Google search that scared me. Will use it now! :)